# How to align two inputs using CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
<form action="" id="delete_reply">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
```

I would like to align the two inputs. How's that possible ?

Update: Because I should have an output inside the form, I added another input outside of it, because both links should look the same.

Comment: Do u have css code ?

Comment: Why is one `input` inside the `form` and the other outside?  And this appears to be using Bootstrap; doesn't it handle things like this?

Comment: you're doing it wrong. The input#text should be within the code

Comment: for some reasons, I need an input outside because I should add one inside and both should look the same (btn-link)

Comment: if you put one outside the form then the data will not get submitted when the form does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the form display to be inline.

```css
form{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
<form action="" id="delete_reply">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have modified your code a little bit please check it might help you**

```css
.form-container{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
<form action="" id="delete_reply">
  <input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this wrapping the content inside a div container setting width to it and to your form and using flex-box like this:

```
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

And

```
.inputs {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.inputs form {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the 1st input inside the form tag.

```css
<form action="" id="delete_reply">
  <input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
```

Or use display: inline-block

```
<style>
  .btn btn-link {
     display: inline-block;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the input tag inside the form

```html
<form action="" id="delete_reply">
  <input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
```

Or if you want to Just keep the html structure as it is and add

```css
form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-link" value="reply">
<form action="" id="delete_reply">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `float: left;` to both of your inputs.